# Deleting objects with FK constraints in Spring/Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

This seems like such a simple scenario to me, yet I cannot for the life of my find a solution online or in print. I have several objects like so (trimmed down):

```
@Entity
public class Group extends BaseObject implements Identifiable<Long> {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Set<HiringManager> managers = new HashSet<HiringManager>();
    private List<JobOpening> jobs;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name="group_hiringManager",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="group_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="hiringManager_id")
    )
    public Set<HiringManager> getManagers() {
        return managers;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="group", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<JobOpening> getJobs() {
        return jobs;
    }
}

@Entity
public class JobOpening extends BaseObject implements Identifiable<Long> {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Group group;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="group_id", updatable=false, nullable=true)
    public Group getGroup() {
        return group;
    }
}

@Entity
public class HiringManager extends User {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="managers", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<Group> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }
}
```

Say I want to delete a Group object. Now there are dependencies on it in the JobOpening table and in the group_hiringManager table, which cause the delete function to fail. I don't want to cascade the delete, because the managers have other groups, and the jobopenings can be groupless. I have tried overriding the remove() function of my GroupManager to remove the dependencies, but it seems like no matter what I do they persist, and the delete fails!

What is the right way to remove this object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before deleting group, iterate over groups job opening list and set null to group field. Or write an update query which nulls job openings table's group field. Something like,

```
Group group = entityManager.find(Group.class, groupId);

for (JobOpening aJob : group.getJobs()) {

     aJob.setGroup(null);
     entityManager.merge(aJob);
     entityManager.flush();
}

//Then delete group

entityManager.remove(group);
```

With query, something like,

```
entityManager.createQuery("update JobOpening set group = null where group.id = :groupId")
             .setParameter(groupId)
             .executeUpdate();
```

Then remove group.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My only question then is how do I work this code into Spring? I imagine it should go in the service layer as it touches multiple models, but I can't figure out how to do an entityManager.flush() from within my manager object. Without that, it fails to delete even when I set the jobs' groups to null and save them via the jobOpeningDao

Comment: If you show a piece of code from your dao, i can suggest better solutions.